Validity of second law of thermodynamics?
Is second law of thermodynamics only valid for isolated systems?
What about closed systems and open systems? Since there is exchange of both mass and energy in open systems, wouldn't that violate 2nd law. Can anyone explain with examples.

Be more specific. Why would you think it only valid for isolated systems? Why would you think exchange of mass and energy would violate it?

I think the exchange of mass and energy may violate it because since there is chance of loss of mass or energy, then the no. Of molecules in the system would decrease, thus the total entropy of the system would decrease.... But of course... If we consider also the surrounding... Then the net entropy may infact increase ... But what about only with respect to the system??

There is nothing wrong with the entropy of the system decreasing

Voting to reopen. A perfectly clear question with good answers below.

For an isolated system, $$\Delta S=\sigma$$where $\sigma$ is the entropy generated due to irreversibility.
For a closed system, $$\Delta S=\int{\frac{dQ}{T_B}}+\sigma$$where $T_B$ is the temperature at the boundary between the system and surroundings through which the heat flow takes place.
For an open system, $$\Delta S=\int{\frac{dQ}{T_B}}+\sigma+\int{s_\text{in}dm_\text{in}}-\int{s_\text{out}dm_\text{out}}$$ where $s_\text{in}$ is the entropy per unit mass flowing in and $s_\text{out}$ is the entropy per unit mass flowing out.

I'm not sure if I understand entirely your question. But here's my perspective about the second law of thermodynamics for isolated, closed and open system. First, it is important to understand the entropy in the formulation of the second of thermodynamics. This entropy is related always to the total entropy - system + surroundings.
Isolated Systems: In isolated systems, neither matter nor energy can exchange with the surroundings. The second law applies straightforwardly here because the system's entropy cannot decrease.
Closed Systems: Closed systems allow the exchange of energy with the surroundings, but not matter. The second law still holds in closed systems. While energy exchange can occur, the total entropy of the system and its surroundings must either remain constant or increase. For instance, consider a gas-filled balloon inside a thermally insulated container. Heat can transfer between the balloon and the container, but the total entropy of the system (balloon + container) must either stay the same or increase.
Open Systems: Open systems can exchange both energy and matter with the surroundings. The second law remains valid here, but its interpretation is more nuanced. While it might seem that an open system could violate the second law due to the exchange of matter and energy, it's crucial to consider the overall entropy change of the system plus its surroundings.
Example 1: A pot of water boiling on a stove is an open system. Heat and water vapor are constantly exchanged with the surroundings. While the entropy of the water might decrease as it transitions to steam (local decrease in entropy due to increased order), the total entropy of the system and its surroundings increases because of the dissipation of heat into the environment, contributing to an overall entropy increase.
Example 2: Consider a biological organism, such as a human being. The human body is an open system that exchanges both energy (through food consumption and heat dissipation) and matter (through breathing, sweating, etc.) with the environment. Despite the local decrease in entropy within the body (for instance, the organization of nutrients into complex biomolecules), the overall entropy of the system (body + environment) increases, maintaining compliance with the second law.

Thank you. Now, I get it
